# Angular8: What is the difference between [attr.title]='myVar' and [title]='myVar'?

Tags: angular, angular-template

Why do some attributes require the "attr." prefix and some don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `[title]="myVar"` is property binding whereas `[attr.title]="myVar"` is attribute binding.

Attribute binding must be used, when DOM property doesn't exist.
For example, `colspan` does not exist DOM property and you must use `attr.colspan="..."`. When you try use `colspan="..."` you get an error in console.
Read up on [attribute binding here](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding).

Comment: Thanks! Concisely put. So in the specific case of title attribute, is one way preferred over the other?

Comment: In all cases, property binding more preferred over attribute binding. Use attribute binding if you get Error in console, or if you want to use some attribute to address the element with CSS selectors